# How to update object property

Tags: javascript, json

i've parsed some data to object and I got the following output to the console

Here I want to change the value of internal to 600

```
console.log(res.INSTANCE_PO);
'[{external:500,internal:500}]'
```

I try to access with `res.INSTANCE_PO['internal'] = 600`; which doesn't work

Here I want to update the port to 600 either,how should I do that ?
I try to change it with `res.VP_APP.PORT = 600` without success

```
console.log(res.VP_APP);

'{"instance_id":"716","application_name":"A1","host":"Ro-d13444","port":500}'
```

Comment: Is `'internal` a typo?

Comment: For first object  `res.INSTANCE_PO[0].internal = 600;` and for second `res.VP_APP.port = 600;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
console.log(res.INSTANCE_PO);
'[{external:500,internal:500}]'
```

The outer brackets `[]` show that the object is actually wrapped in an array with just one item. You can get the first item of an array like so:

```
console.log(res.INSTANCE_PO[0]);
'{external:500,internal:500}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is a String. You must first convert it to an Object:

```
var instancePo = JSON.parse(res.INSTANCE_PO);
instancePo.internal = 600;
```

Comment: Thanks but when I do JSON.parse I got error [SyntaxError: Unexpected token '] , any idea?

Answer (score 1):

> Assuming res is JavaScript Array.

`res.INSTANCE_PO` is an array so you have to access 1st element of array. to update it. so Try

```
  res.INSTANCE_PO[0]['internal'] = 600
```

OR

```
  res.INSTANCE_PO[0].internal = 600
```

> Assuming res is JSON string Array.

- Convert JSON string to javascript Object.

  res.INSTANCE_PO=JSON.parse(res.INSTANCE_PO)
- Use first method.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/dlinx/upzfLuvz/) is Fiddle.

You can check type of variable using `typeof res.INSTANCE_PO`

Comment: Not working either, when I do console.log console.log(res.INSTANCE_PO);  I got   '[{external:500,internal:500}]' and Idea how to update this object ?

Comment: but when I do console.log(res.INSTANCE_PO[0]); I got '    ,that it way?

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @Jivings, you must first convert the string to an object with JSON.parse:

```
resJson = JSON.parse(res.INSTANCE_PO);
```

However, if res.INSTANCE_PO is already an object, this step is not necessary.

Object property names are case sensitive, you must use:

```
resJson[0].internal=600;
```

or

```
resJson[0]['internal']=600
```

Comment: Thanks its not working when I do console.log console.log(res.INSTANCE_PO); I got '[{external:500,internal:500}]' and Idea how to update this object ,in addtion when I do console.log(res.INSTANCE_PO[0]); I got ' ,that it .why?

Comment: Please see the updates in the answer with respect to JSON.parse